# JavaFX searchable combobox (like js select2)

Tags: javafx

I am looking for a component like [select2](https://select2.org/) for JavaFX.

A `ComboBox` which will have a searchable `TextField` when the popup appears and filtered `ListView` below.

Any ideas or something that is done already?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this myself a couple of months ago. The idea is basically that you wrap the `ComboBox` drop-down list in a `FilteredList`, and then you add a listener to the `ComboBox#textProperty()` that changes the predicate for the `FilteredList`.

My class contains a lot of extra functionality such as the option to transform lower case input to upper case and restricting the length of the input. You can just remove those parts if you don't need them.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MCVE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ComboBox<String> box = new ComboBox<String>();
        box.setEditable(true);

        // For the combo box filter to work properly we need to create the item
        // list and wrap it in a FilteredList.
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "OneTwo", "ThreeTwo",
                "OneTwoThree");
        FilteredList<String> filteredItems = new FilteredList<String>(items);

        // Then you need to provide the InputFilter with the FilteredList in the
        // constructor call.
        box.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new InputFilter(box, filteredItems, false));

        box.setItems(filteredItems);

        BorderPane view = new BorderPane();
        view.setCenter(box);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(view));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @author Jonatan Stenbacka
     *
     */
    class InputFilter implements ChangeListener<String> {

        private ComboBox<String> box;
        private FilteredList<String> items;
        private boolean upperCase;
        private int maxLength;
        private String restriction;

        /**
         * @param box
         *            The combo box to whose textProperty this listener is
         *            added.
         * @param items
         *            The {@link FilteredList} containing the items in the list.
         */
        public InputFilter(ComboBox<String> box, FilteredList<String> items, boolean upperCase, int maxLength,
                String restriction) {
            this.box = box;
            this.items = items;
            this.upperCase = upperCase;
            this.maxLength = maxLength;
            this.restriction = restriction;
        }

        public InputFilter(ComboBox<String> box, FilteredList<String> items, boolean upperCase, int maxLength) {
            this(box, items, upperCase, maxLength, null);
        }

        public InputFilter(ComboBox<String> box, FilteredList<String> items, boolean upperCase) {
            this(box, items, upperCase, -1, null);
        }

        public InputFilter(ComboBox<String> box, FilteredList<String> items) {
            this(box, items, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            StringProperty value = new SimpleStringProperty(newValue);

            // If any item is selected we save that reference.
            String selected = box.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null
                    ? box.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() : null;

            String selectedString = null;
            // We save the String of the selected item.
            if (selected != null) {
                selectedString = (String) selected;
            }

            if (upperCase) {
                value.set(value.get().toUpperCase());
            }

            if (maxLength >= 0 && value.get().length() > maxLength) {
                value.set(oldValue);
            }

            if (restriction != null) {
                if (!value.get().matches(restriction + "*")) {
                    value.set(oldValue);
                }
            }

            // If an item is selected and the value in the editor is the same
            // as the selected item we don't filter the list.
            if (selected != null && value.get().equals(selectedString)) {
                // This will place the caret at the end of the string when
                // something is selected.
                Platform.runLater(() -> box.getEditor().end());
            } else {
                items.setPredicate(item -> {
                    String itemString = item;
                    if (itemString.toUpperCase().contains(value.get().toUpperCase())) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            // If the popup isn't already showing we show it.
            if (!box.isShowing()) {
                // If the new value is empty we don't want to show the popup,
                // since
                // this will happen when the combo box gets manually reset.
                if (!newValue.isEmpty() && box.isFocused()) {
                    box.show();
                }
            }
            // If it is showing and there's only one item in the popup, which is
            // an
            // exact match to the text, we hide the dropdown.
            else {
                if (items.size() == 1) {
                    // We need to get the String differently depending on the
                    // nature
                    // of the object.
                    String item = items.get(0);

                    // To get the value we want to compare with the written
                    // value, we need to crop the value according to the current
                    // selectionCrop.
                    String comparableItem = item;

                    if (value.get().equals(comparableItem)) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> box.hide());
                    }
                }
            }

            box.getEditor().setText(value.get());
        }
    }
}
```